Android build failure to transform someAar.aar
So I was trying to build a App on Android and this problem started to appear, I looked for some things but nothing seems to work
I've already tried clearing the gradel cache and also updating Android Studio but it didn't work.
`> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED

Error while dexing.
Failed to transform core-1.14.0-alpha01.aar (androidx.core:core:1.14.0-alpha01) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.`

I'm using these versions "react": "17.0.2","react-native": "0.67.5"
android/Build.gradle:
buildscript {
    println "Running Gradle version: $gradle.gradleVersion"
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}


android/app/Build.gradle:
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nameSample"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "versionSample"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
    splits {
        density {
            enable false
            exclude 'ldpi', 'mdpi'
            compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
        }
        abi {
            enable false
            reset()
            universalApk false
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            splits.abi.enable = false
            splits.density.enable = false
            aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release // para ficar sob responsabilidade do AppCenter
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.4"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:+"
    implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc:+"

    // Add this line here
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')

}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)


It seems in my case updating this library fixed the issue for me.
Changing from:
@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7
To:
@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0
